# Why don't std algorithms take the number of iterations as a parameter

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an iterator to a list, and I want to apply an algorithm to the next N elements in the list. I either have to write my own for loop or use `std::advance` if I want to use an algorithm, but that adds overhead.

Why don't std algorithms have overloads that take a number of iterations to perform instead of an end pointer?

Example:

```
std::list<int>::iterator it;
std::list<int>::iterator out;

// desirable but not possible
std::copy(it, 5, out);

// defeats the point of algorithms to replace common loops
for (size_t i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
{
    *out++ = *it++;
}

// unnecessary overhead
std::copy(it, std::advance(it, 5), out);
```

Comment: Some do, like `std::copy_n`.

Comment: @jrok Doh! Ok that was just an example, what about `std::for_each`?

Comment: Why would `std::for_each` need number of iterations in the first place? Isn't that what the regular for-loop should be used for? Besides, you can pass regular arrays to for-each as well.. Each has their own purpose.. for-range, for-each, for.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Of course `std::for_each` needs to know the number of iterations, it's just received indirectly by the end iterator. What if I only want to call a function on a subset of a container?

Comment: Well you can use a pointer?  `std::for_each(&some_container[index], &some_container[someotherindex], [](type var){....});`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I am using `std::list`

Comment: @NeilKirk: Good question.  I'll make an iterator!

Comment: Oh I see the problem.. list is not random access.. Still, I don't see why `for_each` is to blame.. In fact, this is specifically the list container's problem.. I see your point now however..

Comment: Fact is, it's simpler to just take a start and end point.  Needing a count is the rarity.

Comment: I made an N_iterator but there were unforseen problems. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92d23612536640b3  Caviats: input/output-only iterators not implemented because they would require wierd overhead.  Additionally, any algorithm that does anything with the end except compare would have undefined behavior.  So... this is useless.  Making alternative iterators is NOT the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Because ranges are specified by iterators, and iterators can be formed by arithmetic operations such as

```
f(it, it + 5);
```

While it might be cheaper to specify a number of iterations in some cases (`list` for example), combining iterators and iteration counts in potentially tight loops has a performance cost as well as creating a scenario in which it is much easier for programmers to generally overshoot the end of containers

```
vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3 };
for_each_eg(v, 4, [](int i) { cout << i; });
```

With this strategy, you wind up spending a lot more time doing constraint checking. In practice it's just generally a lot easier to do the right thing in the first place when sticking to iterators and ranges.

```
f(v, v.size());
```

Vs

```
f(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Doesn't sell the idea so much, but then consider how easily the second adapts to:

```
f(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to think how you would implement this using the first syntax.

Comment: Additionally, I think he wanted `f(v.rbegin(), v.size())` which invalidates your sample.  A better sample would be `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin)` where the count is not known until the end is reached.

Comment: You're doing this on a kindle?! O.o Impressive!

Comment: I'm starting to find to typing with Swype increasingly intuitive. Well. I was until I tried to write intuitive.

Comment: "combining iterators and iteration counts in potentially tight loops has a performance cost" Explain? As for going out of bounds, you can do that with many things already, including invalid iterators, so I don't think that's a definitive reason not to have it.

Comment: Combining: if you accept both an iterator range and an iteration count, you have to test against both, either at the start of the loop or per iteration (`it != end && i < iters`). While invalid iterators are a problem, they aren't a new problem introduced by iterators or peculiar to iterators. If you can forget that your pointer or iterator or reference to element N just got invalidated, the problem isn't the the type of addressing because a simple offset would likely have the same problem.